# Memory-optimized Gauss-Seidel iteration on a tridiagonal matrix in Octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, linear-algebra

I'm trying to write a program in Octave that will solve a tridiagonal linear equation system. The specific part is that my data is not saved in a usual nxn matrix, but in a nx3 matrix where each column represents the lower, main and upper diagonal respectively.

I already developed a functional iterative process for usual matrices, but in this case, I somehow can't get the indexing right (I assume, since the code is more or less the same). A(1,1) and A(n,3) are always empty.

```
A = [ 0, 1, 1;
      1, 1, 1;
      1, 1, 0 ]

#  represents M = [ 1, 1, 0; 
#                   1, 1, 1;
#                   0, 1, 1 ]

b = [ 3, 2, 1 ]

n = 3

x_new = [2 2 2]
x_old = [2 2 2]

for iter = 1:16
  disp(iter)
    for i = 1:n

    if i == 1
#      disp(A(i,:))
#      disp("first")
      x_new(i) = (1 / A(i, 2)) * ( b(i) - A(i, 3)*x_old(i+1) );
    elseif i == n
#      disp(A(i,:))
#      disp("last")
      x_new(i) = (1 / A(i, 2)) * ( b(i) - A(i, 1)*x_new(i-1) );
    else
      x_new(i) = (1 / A(i, 2)) * ( b(i) - A(i, 1)*x_new(i-1) - A(i, 3)*x_old(i+1) );
    end    

    x_old = x_new;
  end
end

disp(x_old)
```

Any tips? I'm new to octave and algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*M* is not diagonally dominant nor positive definite. Use function `chol()` for positive definite test.

The assignment `x_old = x_new` should not be in the inner loop:

```
while it < maxit
    x_old = x_new;
    x_new(1) = (1 / A(1, 2)) * ( b(1) - A(1, 3) * x_old(2) );

    for i = 2 : n - 1
        x_new(i) = (1 / A(i, 2)) * ( b(i) - A(i, 1) * x_new(i - 1) - A(i, 3) * x_old(i + 1) );
    end

    x_new(n) = (1 / A(n, 2)) * ( b(n) - A(n, 1) * x_new(n - 1) );

    if norm(x_new - x_old, 'inf') <= max_error
        break
    end
    it = it + 1;
end
```

Comment: You are correct. Both were issues. The code works now!